# How to implement 2 Boolean Fields conditional OR in django filters?

Tags: django, boolean-logic, django-filter, django-filters

I am using django-filters. I want to filter my model with 2 boolean fields "men" & "women". From the image below you can see I have 3 records. 2 records have "men" field checked.

In my template where I have the filter implemented, when I check "men" checkbox, it returns only one record because it is checking AND conditional. How do I implement conditional OR for those Boolean Fields so that is returns the 2nd record as well where it has "men" checked as well?

```
class UserProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
        SUB_CATEGORY_CHOICES=Products.objects.values_list('sub_category',flat=True).order_by('sub_category').distinct('sub_category')
        sub_category=django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(label='Sub Category',field_name='sub_category',to_field_name='sub_category',queryset=SUB_CATEGORY_CHOICES)
        men=django_filters.BooleanFilter(label='Men',field_name='men', widget=forms.CheckboxInput)
        women=django_filters.BooleanFilter(label='women',field_name='women', widget=forms.CheckboxInput)

        class Meta:
            model = Products
            fields = ['sub_category', 'men', 'women']
```

[image]

Comment: Basically you just want the user who are all male. If that is the case, you can do the normal ORM filter. You get the object model and filter where men is true. for example if the User is the model than user=User.objects.filter(men=true)

Comment: I want the user to filter the data. Thats the reason I'm using Django-filters.